Extend the range of Wi-Fi of an ONT using a second router
Here's the situation. I have an ONT (ZTE ZXHN F618) which is my main source of internet (it has Wi-Fi and can run an ethernet cable to anywhere), and I also have a tp-link Archer C80. Currently I run an ethernet cable from the ONT to the TP-Link so I can then run another ethernet cable to my PC for greater internet speeds.
The problem is that the WIFI of the ONT is not that great, it loses one or two bars when I'm in other rooms.
I was thinking if it would be possible somehow to extend the Wi-Fi signal of the ONT using my TP-Link, so to have only one Wi-Fi network, but also keep the ethernet cable connected to my pc using TP-Link so I can have relatively high speeds.
Let me know if that makes any sense :D

For Wi-Fi to work that way, you first need to have a single Ethernet network across both devices.
If the Archer has an "access point" mode, switch it to that mode. (Hopefully it works better in yours than in the C6 I've had.) This will disable the 'router' part and keep only Ethernet and Wi-Fi bridging.
If it doesn't have such a mode: 1) turn off the Archer's DHCP service; 2) change the Archer's LAN IP address to fit the ONT's network; 3) re-connect the Archer using one of its LAN ports instead of the WAN port (ignore that it reports no Internet connection after this).
In short, make sure that devices connected to the Archer end up in the same network as the ONT's LAN, getting the same IP addresses no matter which router's Wi-Fi network or Ethernet port you connect them to – otherwise Wi-Fi devices would suddenly lose connection every time they roam from one to the other.
Finally, change the Archer's Wi-Fi SSID and passphrase to exactly match the ONT's so that client devices would know that they can roam between them. (The channel should remain different.)

Also to note, unless the network is MESH, where the roaming is controlled by the server, not the client, not all clients will switch automatically to better wifi. If that appears to be the case, create 2 separate networks on purpose, so you can switch yourself if you need to, or even choose to forget the ONT one if you're mainly connecting to the TP-Link one.

Thanks a lot! That did the trick :D
